# Boost asio and openssl compatibility

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, openssl, boost-asio

BOOST Asio crashes on openssl code (libssl).

I'm using boost 1.76.
Openssl 1.0.1

I searched for the answer but didn't find anything about that.

Is boost asio 1.76 compatible with openssl 1.0.1

Stack:

```
#0 0x00007f337bbc2bc7 in TLSv1_2_enc_data() from /local/custom/libssl.so.1.1
#1 0x00007f338351ca9d in SSL_CTX_new() from /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
#2 0x00007f3385a71863 in boost::asio::context::context(...) at boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp
```

Comment: It will use the version that compile and link against. If you show your code we can tell.

Comment: I updated the question. 2 openssls are used 10 and 11

Comment: Yeah, so that's not correct. You should probably show how you configured that. What version/package of boost you're using and why your local project links a different version. And then fix that :)